# How to remove the confirmation window from android wear

Tags: android, notifications, android-wear-data-api

[image]

I have done a notification action,but when i click on the action button there is confirmation window is coming.May i know how to remove this screen from android wear ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and according to the quality requirements you shouldn't do that. Take a look at this page for further information : http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html